# Is it possible to pass in a custom controller into custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to pass in a custom controller into custom directive *to be able to use the custom directive on the page with different controllers*?

I can't find a solution for that on docs.angularjs.org

**[Edited]**

Let's say we have the following directive's defenition:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myDirectiveController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'there, dude';
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div>Hello {{name}}!</div>',
            controller: 'myDirectiveController' // can i overwrite it outside this code?
        };
    });
```

Can I simply overwrite the directive's controller not touching the directive's source code itself?

Comment: Look into [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Comment: @Boaz Of course, I’m talking about directive’s controller that does directive specific logic. I’ve edited my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom controller with one HTML template
Then pass your data from that page to directive.
and use that data in HTML template which is assign in directive or also you can write controller in your directive.

```
.controller('myController', function () {

     // write business logic here
     // take some data which you want to use in directive
 });
```

Then pass it through HTML to directive
Use that data in,

```
 .directive('dir', function () {
   return  {
       scope: {
           // collect your data and use it in link
       }    
   };
  });
```

Comment: Pardon, it looks like you don't understand me.
Look at the clarified question, please.

Comment: I don't think, you can overwrite `myDirectiveController` outside, but yes you can use values here from other controller

Comment: It will make me change the directive that isn't mine and I don't want to fork. But I think you are right. There is no way to do what I want.

Comment: but what you want to achieve by doing this ? so we can think in some other way

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of defining the controller in the directive like you have, you can put it in the html template like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ctrl: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-controller="{{ctrl}}">Hello {{name}}!</div>'
    };
});
```

Then I think you will be able to use the directive like:

```
<my-directive ctrl="myDirectiveController"></my-directive>
```

Comment: here in your `ctrl` it will consider myDirectiveController as a string in directive

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how ng-controller works, I am assuming you can pass a string as the name of the controller. But perhaps you do need to pass the actual controller object

Comment: It should work according to the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), but perhaps the `as ctrl` bit is confusing things. I'll edit my answer